# Test suite failed to run in jest with error : no message provided

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

while running jest test on my react i am getting this error for some components and other components are working fine.

```
import { App } from "../App";
import React from "react";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('Render the app component', () => {

    test('Render without crash',async() => {
      await act(async () => {
      render(<App/>);
    });

    test('it should run',()=>{
      expect(2).toBe(2);
    })
});
});
```

whole test suite is failing failing for this test.
error message:

Test suite failed to run

Error: No message was provided

```
import { App } from "../App";
import React from "react";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('Render the app component', () => {
  
  test('it should run',()=>{
    expect(2).toBe(2);
  })


});
```

tests are passing for this.

Comment: anyone please im stuck here

Comment: Have you found out what was the issue?

Comment: There were few things that i hadnt mocked there